# How request spec for 'sharing' function should look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some problems with writing request spec for my function inside Controller. The function is supposed to let the user share the shopping list with another user. I am using FactoryBot.

```
 class ShoppingListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def share
    shopping_list = current_user.shopping_lists.find(params[:id])
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    user_list = UserShoppingList.new(user: user, shopping_list: shopping_list)
    if user_list.save
      flash[:notice] = "Shopping list has been shared"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Shopping list has not been shared"
    end
    redirect_to shopping_lists_path
  end
end
```

**How the share spec should look like? I am stuck on this stage, not sure how can I pass here shopping_list_id and what 'expect' should look like**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ShoppingListsController, type: :request do
  login_user
  let (:user) { controller.current_user }
  let (:shopping_list) { create :shopping_list, user: user }

describe 'share shopping list' do
    it 'let current user share shopping list' do
      post share_shopping_list_path, params: {email: 'user2@gmail.com'}  

  end
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: post share_shopping_list_path(shopping_list), params: {email: 'user2@gmail.com'}  . Would expect that a new list would be created for the user specified by the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is look at the action and pick out what I want to ensure happens, so taking your snippet I'd end up with:

```
- valid shopping list
  - shopping list is created for the target user
  - shows a success message
  - redirects to shopping list index path
- invalid shopping list
  - shows a warning message
  - redirects to shopping list index path
```

Then we can work this into RSpec by making each top level point a context and each point beneath an expectation:

```rb
describe 'share shopping list' do
  let(:params) { { email: 'user2@gmail.com' } }
  # pass route params like id into path helper here
  subject { post share_shopping_list_path, params: params }

  context 'valid shopping list' do
    before do
      # set up a valid shopping list
    end

    it 'shopping list is created for the target user' do
    end

    it 'shows a success message' do
    end

    it 'redirects to shopping list index path' do
    end
  end

  context 'invalid shopping list' do
    before do
      # setup an invalid shopping list
    end

    it 'shows a warning message' do
    end

    it 'redirects to shopping list index path'
    end
  end
end
```

Once you've filled in your expectations, you could consider expanding your test coverage. Perhaps there are multiple cases where you'd expect a shopping list to be invalid (add more contexts) or perhaps you'd like to check the shopping list is created with the same items as the original (add more expectations).